# Add a robots.txt per site in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I use a multisite multilanguage Umbraco CMS.
I have something like this:

```
first.com
second.com
third.com/en
third.com/fr
```

Is there a way to add/manage the `robots.txt` individually for each site...

```
first.com/robots.txt
second.com/robots.txt
third.com/en/robots.txt
third.com/fr/robots.txt
```

in the second instance, the *sitemap* should behave the same way...

(I have the the umbraco v4.7.2)

Using packages like "Cultiv.DynamicRobots" allows only one (even dynamic) robots "per umbraco" installation... and does not permit `third.com/fr/robots.txt`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a url rewrite rule to catch the call to robots.txt and to redirect the request to your own page with the proper logic inside

Answer (score 1):

As Eyescream pointed out, there could be a solution to redirect to a page of a site... 
But with multiple sites and languages that could be some work to do for each one... Another one with same idea I used is having to modify the DynamicRobots component (here is [the source code](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/cultiv-dynamicrobots/requests-and-questions/42417-Source-code)) to read also a QueryString parameter, say "`ln`" of the request.

Then added a redirect from "`mysite.com/fr/robots.txt`" to "`mysite.com/robots.txt?ln=fr`", recuperate Request.QueryString and adding to the site host... `{HTTP_HOST} + QueryString["ln"]`